# Executable Jar: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException sometimes fires when running

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have an executable jar created using Maven, using the assembly plugin like so:

```
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <mainClass>org.htmlcleaner.GUI</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
           <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
              <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The actual Main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new GUI();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });  
}
```

When I package my application, I get a jar-with-dependencies.jar, which I can run by double-clicking it.

However, if I then quit or close the application, and then try to run it again, I sometimes see a ClassNotFoundException in the logs, and the application doesn't launch. (The Exception relates to one of the classes it depends on in the jar. Its definitely there.)

This happens fairly frequently, but not every time. It seems to be any time I try to re-run the application within about 10 seconds of closing it.

Is this just a "one of those things" you get when using Java for desktop apps?

Comment: Paste the `exception` to see where it comes!

Comment: Try to run your app from command prompt `java -jar yourJarFile.jar` this way you will be able to see all output the app write, there may be something there that you don't see in error logs

Comment: If I launch the jar from the command line, it never fails to launch, only occasionally when double-clicking the jar.